# How to properly grip a curved cartridge cover on a single-cartridge faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, kitchen-sink, cartridge, cover

Our kitchen faucet suddenly went down to a slow trickle after making a noise (described by the last user of the sink as a "pop" sound). Other taps in the house work just fine, so we know the issue is localized. I tried removing the faucet head and filter, and the flow is still at a trickle, so I know this isn't due to a clogged filter or a faulty wand.

To the best of my understanding, the next step in diagnosing this is to disassemble the faucet to remove and inspect the cartridge for damage. However, I'm stuck at the step where I am supposed to remove the curved cartridge cover. It seems to have threads which suggests the ability to unscrew it, but it won't budge with the torque I can give it bare-handed. I've heard a strap wrench suggested, but that's not a tool I have, and I wonder whether it might slip off of the curved surface. I also heard penetrating lubricant suggested, but even if I had some on-hand, I would still need a good way to grip this cover.

Before I go out and buy a new faucet, is there anything else I should try? I'm trying to balance the urgency of having a working kitchen sink against my probability of a successful repair as an amateur - and against the guaranteed fix of just replacing the entire faucet.

[image: sink close-up]

Comment: A strap wrench would probably be the best tool and is not expensive.  Next tool would be one that can fit over the end with a piece of rubber between the wrench(pipe)/tool and the finish surface to prevent damage.  The cost difference between a pipe wrench and a strap wrench, the strap will win hands down.  A rubber tube and a stick to twist it down tight might work also. twist tight and use the stick to turn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the water is off before you do anything! The threads may have some corrosion on them. A little penetrating oil would be a good investment before you buy a new faucet. Let the oil sit for a bit on the inrerior threads. Then use a rubber gripper like the type to open jars and attempt to turn it.
It may take some patience and elbow grease but it should turn.

Comment: Of note, there is WD-40, then there is penetrating fluid. ;)